# How to calculate the minimum number of extrinsic dimensions of a metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

## The Question

How does one calculate the minimum number of dimensions of an extrinsic space that can be used to define the metric tensor

\begin{align}
g_{mn}
=
\dfrac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^m}
\dfrac{\partial y_k}{\partial x^n}
\end{align}

where $y^k = (y^1 , y^2 , y^3 , \dots y^{m-2} , y^{m-1} , y^{m})^k$ is the extrinsic space of $m$ dimensions and $x^k = (x^1 , x^2 , x^3 , \dots x^{m-2} , x^{m-1} , x^{n})^k$ is the embedded space of $n$ dimensions.

## Related Question

This questions extends from a previous question: [How to prove the covariant derivative cannot be written as an eigendecomposition of the partial derivative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/how-to-prove-the-covariant-derivative-cannot-be-written-as-an-eigendecomposition).

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of the Nash embedding theorem? If that is the case, maybe math.stackexchange.com would be a better place?

Comment: It should be said that nash only gives a worse case and you can very often do a lot better.